# Go back to previous page in Swift UI after Async func completion

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view with the following code

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
          
  ...

 Button {
    Task {
       await asyncFunction(data:data) {                            
          self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
       }
    }
 } label: {
   Text("Save")
 }
```

And my async function goes as follow:

```
func asyncFunction(data: Data, completion: @escaping () -> Void) async {
  
  // Prepare URL
  let url = URL(string: "api-url")
  guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

  // HTTP Request payload which will be sent in HTTP Request Body
  let d = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)

  ...

  // Perform HTTP Request
  let (responseData, _) = try! await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

  // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
     if let responseData = Optional(responseData) {
         if let dataString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
             print("Response:\n \(dataString)")
         }
     }

  // Call the completion handler
  completion()
}
```

The problem is that, once the the request is complete and it's time to call the `dismiss()`, the app crashes with this error
`Thread 18: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x11022cd24)`.

Looks like a problem with the closure, but not sure to understand what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

1. Floating `Task` like what you have in the `Button` are traditionally considered bad practice because you lose control of the `Task` itself.
2. Completion handlers are a thing of the past when adopting `async await` you should Never (rare exceptions I only know of one) go from `async await` to a completion handler.

If you have to go from a completion handler to `async await` you have to use a `CheckedContinuation`.

Since `async await` acts as if it is synchronous you can just remove the completion handler completely.

```
 Button {
    Task {
       await asyncFunction(data:data)
       self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

    }
 } label: {
   Text("Save")
 }

func asyncFunction(data: Data) async {
  
  // Prepare URL
  let url = URL(string: "api-url")
  guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

  // HTTP Request payload which will be sent in HTTP Request Body
  let d = try! JSONEncoder().encode(data)

  ...

  // Perform HTTP Request
  let (responseData, _) = try! await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

  // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
     if let responseData = Optional(responseData) {
         if let dataString = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
             print("Response:\n \(dataString)")
         }
     }

  // NO Call the completion handler

}
```

Now to get rid of the `Task` you should use `.task`

```
struct AsyncButton: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State private var isProcessingFunction: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isProcessingFunction.toggle()
        } label: {
          Text("Save")
        }.task(id: isProcessingFunction) {
            guard isProcessingFunction else {
                return
            }
            await asyncFunction(data:data)
            dismiss()
            isProcessingFunction = false
        }
    }
}
```

And with this you can take full advantage of `async await`

```
struct AsyncButton: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    @State private var isProcessingFunction: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isProcessingFunction.toggle()
        } label: {
          Text("Save")
                .overlay {
                    //Add a ProgressView
                    if isProcessingFunction {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                }
        }
        .disabled(isProcessingFunction) //Maybe disable button to prevent duplicate calls. Or not to allow the user to cancel the call.
        .task(id: isProcessingFunction) {
            guard isProcessingFunction else {
                return
            }
            await asyncFunction(data:data)
            dismiss()
            isProcessingFunction = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for clearing all these points out! It works as expected!

Comment: I have a form with a picker (navigationLink style). Having the  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss makes the picker freezes when I tap, do you have any idea?

Comment: with this it works: @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode